# Reemplazar una parte de la cadena sin magia

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
text = 'check this regex<placeholder>, it will do what you want';
result = text.replace('<placeholder>', ' `^sql$`');

console.log(result);
```

Como pueden ver, el resultado es

```
check this regex `^sqlcheck this regex, it will do what you want
```

Cuando esperaría que sea

```
check this regex `^sql$`, it will do what you want
```

Por qué pasa esto? y... cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

La función `replace` tiene un comportamiento interesante [respecto al segundo parámetro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter): (las negritas son mías).

> The replacement string can include the following special replacement
>   patterns:
>
> **Pattern**   Inserts
>
> - $$  Inserts a "$".
> - $&  Inserts the matched substring.
> - **$`    Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.**
> - $'  Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.
> - $n  Where n is a positive integer less than 100, inserts the nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a
>     RegExp object. Note that this is 1-indexed.

Traducción aproximada:

El string de reemplazo puede incluir los siguientes patrones de reemplazo:

- `$$` inserta un "$".
- `$&` Inserta el substring que coincide con la búsqueda.
- `` $` `` Inserta la porción del string que precede al substring que coincide con la búsqueda.
- `$'` Inserta la porción del string que sigue al substring que coincide con la búsqueda.
- `$n` Donde n es un número entero positivo y menor a 100, inserta la n-ésima sub-coincidencia entre paréntesis (grupo de captura), asumiendo que el patrón (primer parámetro) es una expresión regular.

Es decir, en este caso se añade `^sql` y tras esto se añade **todo el string que precede al *match***. Se puede solucionar duplicando el carácter $:

```js
const text = 'check this regex<placeholder>, it will do what you want';
const result = text.replace('<placeholder>', ' `^sql$$`');
//                                                  ^^
console.log(result);
```